# why GraphicsMagick parameter -size geometry should be larger than -resize/-thumbnail geometry

Tags: graphicsmagick

I followed the question [square-thumbnails-with-imagemagick-convert](https://superuser.com/questions/275476/square-thumbnails-with-imagemagick-convert) .

according to the answer the **-size** should be larger than the -thumbnail thumbnail . I looked up the mannual page from GraphicksMagick , In the mannual page examples. the -size parameter was set to be equal to the **-resize**. In the mannual ,there is an example as blow:

```
gm convert -size 120x120 cockatoo.jpg -resize 120x120 +profile "*" thumbnail.jpg
```

so I didn't get it why.Can anybody tell me the reason for this, thanks.

Comment: I do not use Graphics magick but can not see any point to the -size in your example code.  Also what happens when you try with the -size bigger or the same?

Comment: @Bonzo I didn't find anything different, that's why i'm confused.

Comment: I would just remove the -size 120x120  and carry on as normal. The -size 120x120 sets a canvas size for example when you are adding text to a plain background. You do not need to do that as you are modifying an image. If you use -define jpeg:size=200x200 as in the example linked to then that gives a "hint" to imagemagick about the image final size. Imagemagick then only loads enough data from the original image to create a 200x200 and so speeding up the process,,

Comment: Yeah . I got your point,  that's what the document saying. I asked here just in case that something is missing behind. From your words, maybe I just think too much @Bonzo